# Prove that integration . Help?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have a question.
I solved [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iojLs.png) but I couldn't find the end.
Firstly This integral is a Sine Integral.
I expanded that as using the product-sum formulas. Thus,

$$\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x} = \frac{3\sin(x) - \sin(3x)}{4x}$$

Then I took integral them one by one and found that

$$= \frac{3Si(x)}{4} - \frac{Si(3x)}{4} + C$$

I don't know how I use $Si(x)$. Can you help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727509/integral-question-please-help-me

Comment: Why are the questions  suspiciously similar?

Comment: @AshWhole Really ? Maybe coincidence ? I have no idea.

Comment: That person is also Turkish.

Comment: @AshWhole There was that question in a book. It can be same book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of ${Si(x)}$ is ${\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt}$. In terms of solving the integral indefinitely - you are done. If you want to solve this indefinitely, however, say ${\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(t)}{t}dt}$, then notice ${Si(0)=0}$, and indeed since ${\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}}$ we have ${\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}Si(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and hence you get

$${=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}Si(x)-\frac{Si(3x)}{4}\right)-(0)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

And you are done.

Comment: Thank you so muchh.